# How to identify the reference of a button

Tags: android, android-button

In java, after creating a button this way:

```
Button button1= new Button();
```

i can identify the reference of a button this way

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent bottonName){            
            Button name_of_the_button= (Button)bottonName.getSource();
                    //Inside 'name_of_the_button' I have 'button1'
}
```

How can i do the same on android? I tried this way

```
 public void onClick(View bottonName) {
            Button name_of_the_button= (Button )bottonName.getSource();
}
```

But on android there isn't the method getSource().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Button name_of_the_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
```

then

```
name_of_the_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v.getId() == R.id.my_btn) {

                              // button action here

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check as following:

```
Button button1= new Button();

button1.setOnClickListener(this);    

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (view.getId() == button1.getId())
        {
            //Perform something
        }

    }
```

So both ids will be matched (clicked button's id and one which you created through Java code)

Comment: You have to register `onClickListener` for `Button button1`... :-)

Comment: @user370305, I think OP is implementing the class as onClickListener because OP hasn't registered listener for specific button.

Comment: Then also he need to register for `Button button1` else `onClick` for `button1` never be called.

Comment: @user370305, Ok :) Got that. Missed the line. Editing

Answer (score 0):

```
Button but1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); within the onCreate of your layout
```

followed by the listener

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.but1) {

                          // your code here

        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Android != Corejava`. In order to have your method work, you need to define the onClick by `android:onClick = "buttonClick"` for your button in xml.

Then your onClick method would be

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
 Button button = (Button)view; // here is the reference.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a button and then add this to `main layout` as a child then set `click listener` on that button

```
Button buyButton = new Button(this);
    buyButton.setText(R.string.button_back);
    buyButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(buyButton);
buyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
// Do What you want on click

}});
```

Answer (score 0):

In android a View occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is responsible for drawing and event handling. View is the base class for widgets, which are used to create interactive UI components (buttons, text fields, etc.)
So for you to call button you must first declare the button

```
Button nameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttononyourXML);
```

OR 
you could create it programmatically using

```
ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourLinear);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("A Button");
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linerLayout.addView(btn);
```

Then add a listener based on your required method

Its your choice..

Cheers